# Store elasticsearch date across different timezones and query it without timezone

Tags: elasticsearch, timezone-offset, timestamp-with-timezone

ONE elastic index that stores visitor data for restaurants in chennai and in New york.

The query must return data for  8-9am in chennai and 8-9am in newyork. Since the data is in one index, is there a way to ignore the timeszone in the timestamp and query elastic data?
or is it possible to solve this problem without multiple query?

Answer (score 1):

The approach I am taking is to convert and store **local date time** (without timezone info) into a long integer yymmddhhmmss and query it. This will support lte and gte queries too.

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible, no, because they are two totally different timezones/timestamps